# Shortest way to make web address absolute in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have a string with a web address in it which may or may not include the protocol at the beginning. This is going into the href of a html a tag so needs to include the protocol to avoid the address being treated as a relative address. What's the shortest code to achieve this. Just to be clear, the possible inputs and expected outputs are below.

string url = "www.google.com"; //expected "http://www.google.com"

string url = "google.com"; //expected "http://google.com"

string url = "http://www.google.com"; //expected "http://www.google.com"

string url = "https://www.google.com"; //expected "https://www.google.com"

Update:

To those that want to know what I already tried, it was a couple of if statements checking if the url already started with one of the relevant prefixes and then appending it on if necessary. This is trivial for any c# programmer but doesn't come close to the "shortest way". It worked without any problems but my question is to see what better ways there are of doing it.

Comment: Care to tell us what you've tried?

Comment: make a web request and follow all redirects.

Comment: The protocol doesn't make it relative, that.s not what the protocol portion of a URI does

Comment: @CodeUniquely Without the protocol, the address behaves like a relative address so "Google.com" goes to "siteaddress.com/google.com". When the protocol is part of the address, its recognised as an absolute address.

Comment: well, you learn something new everyday :)

Comment: @nickgrim my solution was something similar to the answer from Ahmed. Not very satisfying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `UriBuilder` class for this.

```
public static Uri GetUri(this string s)
{
    return new UriBuilder(s).Uri;
}
```

> This constructor initializes a new instance of the UriBuilder class with the Fragment, Host, Path, Port, Query, Scheme, and Uri properties set as specified in uri.

**If uri does not specify a scheme, the scheme defaults to "http:".**

Comment: Works nicely in all of the cases. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> This is going into the href of a html a tag so needs to include the protocol to avoid the address being treated as a relative address

You can simply use `//` to let the browser know it's an absolute url and not a relative path, the browser will then use `http` or `https` appropriately (based on the current page context).

For example:

```
//www.google.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only http/https protocols are expected:

```
if (!url.StartsWith("https://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
       && !url.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    url = "http://" + url;
```